# Qt linking problems

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, qtgui

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   setCentralWidget(ui->plainTextEdit);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionDoit_triggered()
{
    Dialog D;
    D.setModal(true);
    D.exec();
}
```

This small piece of code is giving me linker errors LNK2019 and LNK1120
If I remove the three lines in function **void MainWindow::on_actionDoit_triggered()**, it works. The tutorial I am following didn't warn of linker problems

Comment: If the code compiles correctly and I have linker errors, I delete the build folder and rebuild and it seems to compile and link fine, not sure why though

Comment: What are you doing to compile the program? Plain compilation, *Qt Creator*, *QMake*? **Edit**: can you give a link to the tutorial?

Comment: Well i am using the MSVC compiler and also i am building it using the build button(ctrl + B)

Comment: What exactly is the complete text of the link errors?

Comment: http://imgur.com/hlAtzwG

Comment: Try deleting the build folder, and rebuilding, there shouldn't be a reason why those externals are unresolved if they compile properly

Comment: Just to make sure... Are Dialog::Dialog() {} and Dialog::~Dialog() {} defined in dialog.cpp?

Comment: Yes. It got fixed, when i ran qMake(after right clicking on the project), dont know why, can someone clarify this for future purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you got it working without changing the code just by re-running qmake explicitly.

The reason is most likely the fact that you modified your qmake project file(s), and QtCreator has issues with knowing when to re-run qmake properly.

There is a long-standing bug about it:

[Creator should know when to rerun qmake](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-231)